# What is the military term for kicking militants out of a city?

Tags: meaning, military

What is the military term for driving militants out of a city, and declaring the city completely militant-free?

I got an advice to use the word "cleansed", but I am not really convinced it is the right word.

Comment: Neutralize is one word. Also, *the area is cleared of hostiles*.

Comment: _Pacification_ is "to rid an area of terrorists or other enemies by military force or psychological persuasion".

Comment: A less formal expression that is used is "taking out the trash".

Comment: *Occupation* works

Comment: *Cleanse* has negative connotations because of the euphemism *ethnic cleansing*, used to refer to forced migrations and genocide in post-Yugoslav states in the 1990s. If you say an army is *cleansing* an area, you are associating them with war criminals. *Purify* has similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

expelled 
*verb*

> to drive or force out or away; discharge or eject: for example,
>   to expel air from the lungs; or to expel an invader from a country.

They expelled the militants from the city makes sense.